# JAVA: Byte array allocation in InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)

Tags: java, file, byte, arrays, inputstream

I have a big file from which I want to get bytes divided in 20,000,000 bytes chunks.

I wrote a code like this:

```
File clipFile = new File("/home/adam/Temp/TheClip.mp4");
InputStream clipIStream = new FileInputStream(clipFile);

long chunkSize = 20000000;

long fileSize = clipFile.length();
long totalParts = (long) Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize);

for(int part=0; part < totalParts; part++) {
    long startOffset = chunkSize * part;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)chunkSize];
    clipIStream.read(bytes, (int) startOffset, (int) chunkSize));

    // Code for processing the bytes array
    // ...
}
```

The program crashes after the first iteration, generating `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

After consulting [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) I found the following:

> public int read(byte[] b,
>                  int off,
>                  int len)
>           throws IOException
>
> (...)
>
> The first byte read is stored into element b[off], the next one into
>   b[off+1], and so on.

It means, that on second iteration `read` begins writing on position bytes[20000000], instead of bytes[0] as I would want it.

Is there any way to achieve writing bytes on the beginning of the bytes array on every iteration?

Comment: Yes - you pass in 0 as the second argument... it's as simple as that. Note that you shouldn't *assume* you'll be able to read the whole chunk each time though - you should use the return value of `read` to see how many bytes you've actually read. Additionally, you may well want to reuse the same byte array for all iterations...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, now I got it working

Comment: I just noticed your updated answer. You made good points, especially with using the return value of read. I quickly found the fixed size of bytes array is a problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pass `startOffset` into [the `read` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-).

> off - the start offset in array b at which the data is written.

The offset is into the array, not into the stream.  Pass `0` instead, to write from the beginning of the array.

Comment: So it means that `read` simply moves internal pointer in the InputStream, is this correct?

Comment: Wonderful, that makes everything clear. Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer when the time limit passes.